# how to animate svg filter feComponentTransfer?

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

Anyone know how to use animate tag in feFuncRGB in feComponentTransfer? I have a SVG filter and I need to show/hide it on click with some transition.

something like that:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg-filters">
    <filter id="duotone">
        <feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" result="duotone_cyan_blue">
            <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.2489 0.9589">
                <animate 
                id="animate"
                attributeName="tableValues" 
                dur="2s" 
                from="0 1" 
                to="0.2489 0.9589" 
                fill="freeze" 
                />
            </feFuncR>
        </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
</svg>
```

Same things for feFuncG and feFuncB

```
$('img').click( function() {
  $("#animate").beginElement();
});
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be using an svg image like so:

```js
svg.addEventListener("click",() =>{
  _animate.beginElement();
})
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg" width="300" height="300" >
    <filter id="duotone">
        <feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" result="duotone_cyan_blue">
            <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0 1">
               <animate 
                id="_animate"
                attributeName="tableValues" 
                dur="2s" 
                values="0 1;1 0" 
                fill="freeze"
                begin="svg.click"
                />
            </feFuncR>
        </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
  
  <image xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/darwin300.jpg" width="300" height="300" filter="url(#duotone)"></image>
</svg>
```